# Calculate miter points of stroked vectors in Cartesian plane

Tags: geometry

I have two vectors **CA** and **CB** which I 'stroked' with lines of width **a** and **b**. I need to calculate **D** and **E** points to draw miter joint between two stroked vectors. 
What I know is:

- **A** point coordinates
- **B** point coordinates
- **C** point coordinates
- **β** angle
- **a** length
- **b** length

What I'm looking are coordinates of points **D** and **E**. I need to find universal formula that lets me to calculate those points at any β. (please see pic.1 below)

[image]

I can calculate those points if use stroke with same length for both vectors (**a** == **b**). I'm doing it by reflecting point **C** over vector **AC** with distance **0.5*a**. Then I have right angle triangle, on which **γ** angle at point **C** equals **90° - (0.5 * β)** angle. Therefore I have all three angles for the triangle and length of **CF** (half of **a**) which lets my to calculate coordinates of point **D**. (please see pic.2 below). I use triangle **CGE** to calculate **E** coordinates in the same way as above.

[image]

My problems start when I need to use different width for the vector's stroke (**a** != **b**) (please see pic.3 below). In that case when I draw **CFD** triangle I cannot calculate **γ** angle as it is not **90° - (0.5 * β)** anymore and I have no idea how to calculate **D** and **E** coordinates. Can someone point me in the right direction how to find **γ** angle or if there is any other (better) way to calculate coordinates of **D** and **E**?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Draw two vectors $\vec u$ and $\vec v$ as in the picture below. They form a parallelogram having $a/2$ and $b/2$ as altitudes. It follows that
$$
u={b\over 2\sin\beta},\quad v={a\over 2\sin\beta}.
$$
It is then easy to compute $\vec u$ and $\vec v$:
$$
\vec u={A-B\over AB}{b\over 2\sin\beta},\quad
\vec v={C-B\over BC}{a\over 2\sin\beta}
$$
and finally:
$$
D=B+\vec u+\vec v,\quad E=B-\vec u-\vec v.
$$

[image]

Comment: Amazing! It looks much cleaner and simpler from what I was trying to do. I know it may be pretty basic, but I'm not sure how to do computations on points (A-B/AB), therefore I'm not sure how to compute u⃗ and v⃗. Are A, B and C row matrices in your equation? Would you mind to show me an example calculation?

Comment: $A-B$ and $C-B$ are displacement vectors. Example: $A=(1,3)$, $B=(5,1)$, $A-B=(-4,2)$. While $AB$ is the distance between $A$ and $B$. For the example at hand, $AB=\sqrt{20}$ so that $${A-B\over AB}=(-{4\over\sqrt{20}},{2\over\sqrt{20}}).$$